# Второстепенный член между подлежащим и сказуемым, выраженными существительными

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, тире, сказуемые

Есть правило. Между подлежащим и сказуемым, выраженными существительными, при наличии наречия либо второстепенного члена, относящегося к сказуемому, тире не ставится.

Однако иногда подлежащее и/или сказуемое имеет сложный состав, и кажется необходимым разграничить их при помощи тире:

> 1. Неизвестность — также элемент игры.
> 2. Сведение с нужным человеком — тоже услуга, за которую вас будут вспоминать добрым словом.
> 3. Изучение английского для неё — ключик к достижению цели.

Является ли такая постановка тире правильной? Есть ли какое‑то правило на этот счёт? Нашёл только [у Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92#pp92) исключение в случае отрицания:

> Постановка тире в этом случае имеет целью логически и интонационно подчеркнуть сказуемое: Но объяснение — не оправдание (М. Г.); Его взгляды на семейный этикет — не предрассудок ли это?;.

При этом иногда возникает вопрос, куда ставить второстепенный член — до или после тире:

> 4.1. Так что интернет-маркетинг — сегодня отличное направление для развития.
>
> 4.2. Так что интернет-маркетинг сегодня — отличное направление для развития.
>
> 5.1. Практика от вуза в большинстве случаев — бесполезная трата времени.
>
> 5.2. Практика от вуза — в большинстве случаев бесполезная трата времени.

Answer (score 2):

В справочнике Лопатина правило выглядит так: 
http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=106

> § 10. Между подлежащим и именным сказуемым на месте отсутствующей
>   связки ставится тире, если подлежащее и сказуемое выражены
>   существительными в форме именительного падежа: Флигель у дома на
>   Садовой по проекту Михаила Александровича Врубеля — единственное
>   строение из владений Мамонтовых, почти сохранившее свой внешний вид до
>   наших дней (Кис)...
>
> **Примечание.** Тире может не ставиться, если в письменной речи отражено произношение с логическим ударением на сказуемом: Моя сестра
>   учительница (ср.: Моя сестра — учительница — ударение и на слове
>   сестра, и на слове учительница). Тире обязательно:  1) если имеется
>   сопоставление: Моя сестра — учительница, а брат — зоотехник; 
>   **2) если возможна синтаксическая или смысловая двусмысленность; ср.: Брат — мой учитель и Брат мой — учитель.**

Это так называемое интонационное тире, которое необходимо
для внесения ясности в смысл предложения, ведь оно подчеркивает интонационное расчленение предложения на состав подлежащего и состав сказуемого.

> Неизвестность — также элемент игры.
>
> Сведение с нужным человеком — тоже услуга, за которую вас будут
>   вспоминать добрым словом.
>
> Изучение английского для неё — ключик к достижению цели.

```
     Является ли такая постановка тире правильной?
```

Конечно, эти примеры как раз иллюстрируют выделение сказуемого с помощью паузы, обозначенной тире.

Последние Ваши примеры - примеры двусмысленности:

> 4.1. Так что интернет-маркетинг — сегодня отличное направление для развития.
>
> 4.2. Так что интернет-маркетинг сегодня — отличное направление для развития.
>
> 5.1. Практика от вуза в большинстве случаев — бесполезная трата времени.
>
> 5.2. Практика от вуза — в большинстве случаев бесполезная трата времени.

Какой смысл автор имеет в виду, там он и ставит тире, отграничивая состав сказуемого и перенося на него фразовое ударение.

Comment: Но обстоятельства «сегодня» и «в большинстве случаев» по смыслу относятся к всему предложению, а не к составу подлежащего или сказуемого. Так что смысл в обоих случаях один и тот же. Я слышал, что в подобных случаях тире ставится не по смыслу, а таким образом, чтобы фразы по объёму были примерно равновесными.

Answer (score 2):

По правилам при наличии между подлежащими и сказуемым наречия, союза и других слов тире  можно не ставить.

А можно и поставить, если сделать паузу. А если поставить, то куда отнести наречие или союз?

**Все эти вопросы  решаются в рамках контекста,** потому что постановка тире зависит от расстановки логических ударений в предложении, что определяется по общей семантике, которую выражает данное сообщение или текст.

**Например:**

1) ***НеизвЕстность — также элемент игры,  ее составная и, даже можно сказать, главная часть. Неизвестность тАкже элемент игры, но это не самоцель.***

Разный смысл, разные логические ударения и решения тоже разные.

2) *Так что интернет-маркетинг — сегодня отличное направление для развития.*

Некорректно! Где ставить логическое ударение? Непонятно где. Как читать — тоже неизвестно.

Редактируем: ***Так что сегОдня интернет-маркетинг — отличное направление для развития.***  Похоже на вывод. Теперь всё читается, и слово *сегодня* на своем месте.

**Примечание**

Не далее как вчера читала я книгу Мучника Б. С. "Основы стилистики и редактирования". Автор — известный специалист, развивающий особое, психологическое направление в стилистике. Первый же параграф  посвящен теме логических ударений, от которых во многом зависит взаимопонимание между пишущим и читающим. В частности, рассмотрены способы определения того слова в предложении, на которое автор текста ставит  ударение (или хотел поставить, но не получилось).

Comment: *«Так что интернет-маркетинг — сегодня отличное направление для развития». Некорректно! Где ставить логическое ударение? Непонятно где*.

Логическое ударение на слове «интернет-маркетинг»: «Так что (именно) интернет-мАркетинг — сегодня отличное направление для развития».

Comment: Вот об этом и говорится в книге по стилистике. Автор думает, что он поставил ударение в нужном  месте, а читатель этого не понимает, не слышит.  Да и предложение ваше "не читается".  Это уже на слух надо определять.  Правильный текст читается плавно, легко, без запинок, и смысл, и ударные позиции схватываются на лету. Слово "сегодня"  в ваших предложениях никуда не клеится. Хотите ударение на "интернет" поставить? Тогда используйте слово-усилитель.

Comment: Получим:  Так что  сегодня именно интернет-маркЕтинг - отличное направление для развития. А еще лучше: И сегодня именно интернет-маркЕтинг - отличное направление для развития. Вот это предложение читается! Может, вам и не очень всё это понятно, но в полном объеме эту тему "долго рече".

Comment: А если в приведённом вами варианте "Так что сегодня именно интернет-маркЕтинг — отличное направление для развития» обстоятельство «сегодня» переместить туда, куда я хочу, а именно между подлежащим и сказуемым, нужно ли будет ставить тире? И если да, то слово «сегодня» будет стоять до или после тире?

Comment: Здравствуйте!  Как ваши дела?  Это я для вежливости говорю (давно же  не виделись), да и вообще интересно. Что касается вашего вопроса, то, увы, вариант здесь единственный. Любая перестановка слов влияет на семантику и грамматику, это только кажется, что мы можем их "кидать" туда-сюда. Обстоятельство в начале предложения является детерминантом (относится ко всему предложению).  Если его  поставить  до тире, то оно будет обстоятельственным определением для подлежащего,  если  после тире,  то  вообще будет непонятно чем.  Без тире тоже нельзя, состав подлежащего и сказуемого будет неявным.

Comment: Вы на слух проверяйте предложения. Носители языка выбирают порядок слов по интуиции, обычно мало кто может объяснить, как он это делает. Прочитайте варианты и сравните, мне кажется выбрать  наилучший (а иногда и единственный) не так сложно,  так как мы чувствуем мелодику (интонацию)  текста. Хотите объяснить? Тогда надо расставлять паузы и логические ударения.

Comment: У меня всё отлично. Иногда в жизни наступают времена, когда в работе становится не до стилистики и чётко выверенного синтаксиса)) А сейчас снова появилось время на совершенствование своего языка. Вы как?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, рада вас здесь видеть. Хотелось бы, чтобы наши участники форума проявили к вам максимум внимания. Вы мне нравитесь, но у нас мышление разное: у вас ближе к формальной логике, а мне она кажется  неоправданно линейной,  многомерное пространство привлекает больше. Поэтому мы часто не понимаем друг друга, но это не мешает мне относиться к вам с симпатией. Что касается лично меня, то я каждый день собираюсь отсюда "сбежать", возможно, когда-нибудь мне это удастся. Но я все равно буду издали наблюдать за вами, так что заходите, задавайте вопросы.

Comment: Очень приятно ваше внимание ко мне) Касательно того, что вы хотите «сбежать»… Вас опять обижают — ругают и не оценивают по достоинству ваши ответы? Или вам просто надоело и вы не видите своего развития здесь?

Comment: Спасибо и вам за внимание. Это хороший ресурс, мне кажется, что лучше найти трудно. Здесь хорошая посещаемость, контент обновляется быстро, много интересных вопросов, то есть практического материала для собственного развития очень  много. Форум интересно посещать, даже не отвечая на вопросы. Так что заходите чаще, если хотите быть в курсе современных проблем в языке, не пожалеете. Что касается морального климата, то мне здесь не очень комфортно. Негативных моментов, конечно,  хватает, но дело даже не в этом.

Comment: Здесь, как и везде, преобладает формальный подход к языку,  а он не должен быть таким.  Современное развитие во всех областях жизни  сводится к преодолению формализма, к многомерности, к многозначности: мир – виртуальный, человек – виртуальный.  Я вижу, как эти идеи  реализуются в грамматике, как там всё стремительно меняется, а вот  понимание русской системы письма  так и осталось в прошлом веке. Что-то изменить у меня не получается. Единомышленников практически нет,  поэтому нет и особого интереса к моим вопросам и ответам.

Comment: Я вас понимаю. Насчёт формального подхода, который вы приписали и мне тоже, я скажу следующее. Если речь идёт о формальном подходе как о бездумном следовании формальностям в ущерб содержанию — я против такого подхода. Опишу свою систему взглядов и ценностей на этот счёт. Она лишена противоречий формального подхода и индивидуального подхода к каждому конкретному случаю. Возможно, она поможет примерить вашу парадигму с парадигмой других участников сообщества.

Comment: Я согласен с существованием многомерности и бесконечного числа частных случаев, каждый из которых уникален. Но это хаос. Человек в этом хаосе не может эффективно решать проблемы жизни. Поэтому он стремится в этом бесконечном множестве частностей найти общие черты, с тем чтобы упорядочить хаос. И правильно делает. И самое главное — общие черты в этом хаосе действительно есть, ничего притягивать за уши не нужно.

Comment: Я против того, чтобы насильно подбивать все частные случаи под какое-то известное правило, когда это неправомерно. Если есть частный случай, для которого не применимо ни одно из правил, нужно решать вопрос в индивидуальном порядке. Но когда накапливается некоторое количество сходных частных случаев, для которых пока нет системы, искать правило, которое сможет их упорядочить, — это наш долг как человека разумного.

Comment: И по-моему, такое «новое» правило, способ решения для доколе не объяснённых частных случаев вы часто формулируете в своих ответах.

Comment: Насколько я понял, вы протестуете против неправомерного притягивания  случаев, для которых правила пока нет, к существующим правилам. Вы за НОВЫЕ решения. Но когда накапливается достаточное количество прецедентов использования какого‑то нового решения, его нужно обличить в правило — формализовать. Вы согласны? Если да, то вы тоже за формальный подход:))

Comment: Я дам  вам новый ответ вместо комментария, а то здесь уже мало места.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ на комментарии

Спасибо за ваши комментарии. Хотя у нас разные мнения, но ваша точка зрения помогла мне точнее определиться в ряде вопросов. Возражая кому-то, лучше понимаешь проблему сам.

**О ФОРМАЛЬНОМ ПОДХОДЕ**

Слово «формальный» может иметь как позитивное, так и негативное значение. Если вы подробно изучаете грамматическую форму, то что же в этом плохого?

Но содержание русской речи передается двумя формами – **грамматической и структурно-интонационной**. Вторая форма особенно важна при работе с аудиторией, когда нужно не только точно изложить мысль,  но сделать это эмоционально, ярко, убедительно.
И вот  при изучении  этой формы желательно иметь дело  **с «живыми» текстами,** так как структуру мы выбираем **интуитивно**. Не стоит забывать, что любые переделки предложения могут  ухудшить его, а то и вовсе «убить».

**О НОВЫХ ПРАВИЛАХ**

Формализм наших правил другой: он настаивает **на единственном решении** там, где их просматривается несколько. Надо сказать, что проблема неоднозначного решения касается в основном пунктуации.

**Я – за правила**, но вот только наши правила – **это и не правила вовсе,  а комментарии к примерам.**

В таком виде они были написаны в 1956 году,  а потом их количество (при детальной проработке тем) просто значительно увеличилось, а качество осталось таким же.

**Вы хотите множить их и дальше?**  Вот тогда уж и наступит настоящий **хаос.**

Нет, количество правил надо сократить, но при этом **переосмыслить:** дать им теоретическую основу, обозначить общий принцип решения и назвать все возможные варианты форм написания и их значения. Тогда не составит большого труда подобрать нужный вариант  для любого конкретного примера.

Да и запоминать мало что придется, пользователи научатся **решать свои задачи сами**, оставаясь в рамках правил. Я за такое "новое решение" и за такой "формализм". И разве это не разумный подход? К тому же он соответствует законам диалектики: нам нужны настолько совершенные правила, что они будут отрицать  сами себя.

Но это **дело будущего**, а сейчас приходится работать с тем, что есть. В то же время  надо понимать всю сложность ситуации: хотя мы работаем по правилам, но эти правила имеют ограниченные возможности, в частности проблему выбора при наличии вариантов (например, двоеточие или тире) они не решают.

Comment: Я внимательно прочитал ваш ответ. И знаете, я с ним согласен. В существующих правилах русского языка действительно просто написаны типовые примеры и решения к ним без описания ОБЩЕЙ ЛОГИКИ выбора того или иного решения. Видимо, эту логику вы и называете «теоретической основой», которую необходимо заложить.